# Recover files from lost+found to original location

Tags: boot

Please help me. I am in a trouble. After  I performed a "fsck" system check my ubuntu automatically goes to initramfs prompt . Everything from my home folder was removed. I came to know that all files are moved to lost+found folder. Now please someone help me how to recover files of my home folder from lost+found folder.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://blog.windfluechter.net/content/blog/2011/03/30/1095-updated-automatically-restore-files-lostfound). It is a simple script, but still seems to be useful.